# How do I add a marker to google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've created a custom map which I'm happy with. I've tried to implement the marker as per the documentation but something's going wrong?

Developer tool is telling me there's a reference error and my latling is not defined. Not sure how to resolve it.

This is what I have:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.523612, -0.125816);

        var styles = [{
            "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -100
            }, {
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -100
            }]
        }, {
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {}];

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            styles: styles
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Hello World!"
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have defined any variabke 'mylatlng'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the begining of code there is

```
var latlng = ...
```

and at the end you use `myLatLng`.

Those are different and you should use the same. Change `myLatLng` to `latlng`.

Or if you want the marker to be somewhere else you should define `myLatLng` first (just as you define `latlng` at the begining) and then create the marker.

Comment: This must be a typo. I mean, we can't really be dealing with an OP who *doesn't understand variable assignment*... Can we?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.523612, -0.125816)
```

where the var is `latlng` but below try to define it with

```
position: myLatlng,
```

I don't see `myLatlng` referenced anywhere else